# How to run django-project?

Tags: python, linux, django, virtualenv, linux-mint

please help to solve the problem.

I created the following directory structure for django-project:

```
blogik5_project
    -blogik5_env
        -bin
        -lib
        -local
    -blogik5
        -
        -
        -
```

in the file home/.profile prescribed:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs/blogik5_project
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs/blogik5_project/blogik5
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

switched to a virtual environment:

```
workon blogik5_env
```

moved to the directory blogik5_project/blogik5

run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

as a result received the following error message:

```
(blogik5_env)kalinins@kalinins-Lenovo-Z580 ~/.virtualenvs/blogik5_project/blogik5 $ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install django with pip:

```
pip install django
```

Next,

```
django-admin.py startproject nameOfProject
```

More documentation in:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/